# How can I know how much time has passed between calling receive and receiving a message?

Tags: elixir

This is a sample process that will take an option among three specific initial Poker options:

```
defmodule PokerTable do
  # ...more stuff here - in particular, implementations
  # ...  of process* and has_bet functions, state initialization
  # ...  and more irrelevant stuff 

  defp ask_option_on_no_bet(currentTableState) do
    user = currentTableState.currentUser
    newTableState = receive do
      { ^user, :bet, amount } -> process_bet(currentTableState, amount)
      { ^user, :check } -> process_check(currentTableState)
      { ^user, :fold } -> process_fold(currentTableState)
      after 15000 -> process_check(currentTableState)
    end
  end

  defp ask_option_on_bet(currentTableState) do
    user = currentTableState.currentUser
    newTableState = receive do
      { ^user, :raise, amount } -> process_raise(currentTableState, amount)
      { ^user, :call } -> process_check(currentTableState)
      { ^user, :fold } -> process_fold(currentTableState)
      after 15000 -> process_fold(currentTableState)
    end
  end

  def ask_option(currentTableState) do
    if has_bet(currentTableState) do 
        ask_option_on_no_bet(currentTableState)
    else
        ask_option_on_bet(currentTableState)
    end
  end
end
```

In this case, this PokerTable is just a sample module resembling a poker interface. Those who play in online poker sites will be quite aware of what this interface means, and one reason to like Elixir was the out of the box ability to do this.

The meaning of the code is: *when a new message arrives, read the internal messages stack to find whether the arriving messages match any of these clauses, and process it. If no matching message was received after 15 seconds since this call, then perform a default action*.

This approach, while tempting, has a caveat: Non-matching messages will be kept in the internal process' message box (which is a FIFO), which implies two things:

- You can **eat my memory** by sending invalid messages right now, which cannot be processed and will be held in the box.
- A bugged (or malicius) client may send out-of-turn messages for a specific user (which has no turn right now!). Those messages will be valid when the user's turn comes, and will be processed.

Then I could think the following approach for both `receive` blocks:

```
  defp ask_option_on_no_bet(currentTableState) do
    user = currentTableState.currentUser
    newTableState = receive do
      { ^user, :bet, amount } -> process_bet(currentTableState, amount)
      { ^user, :check } -> process_check(currentTableState)
      { ^user, :fold } -> process_fold(currentTableState)
      anyJunk ->
        tell_the_user_they_sent_junk(user)
        ask_option_on_no_bet(currentTableState)
      after 15000 -> process_check(currentTableState)
    end
  end

  defp ask_option_on_bet(currentTableState) do
    user = currentTableState.currentUser
    newTableState = receive do
      { ^user, :raise, amount } -> process_raise(currentTableState, amount)
      { ^user, :call } -> process_check(currentTableState)
      { ^user, :fold } -> process_fold(currentTableState)
      anyJunk ->
        tell_the_user_they_sent_junk(user)
        ask_option_on_bet(currentTableState)
      after 15000 -> process_fold(currentTableState)
    end
  end
```

Now I am avoiding storing crap in the message queues. So far, so good. However this results in a new call to `receive`, which will **reset the timer**, because the `after` runs since the current `receive` call.

What I thought, then, was to:

- Retrieve the currently elapsed miliseconds between the `receive` and the junk command.
- Subtract `15000 - theRetrievedElapsedMiliseconds` and keep that value as a member of the state (that we'd update in this case, and we'd initialize to 15000 on `ask_option`).
- Instead of `after 15000`, use two lines: `remainingTime = currentTableState.remainingTime` and `after remainingTime` in the `receive` block (and update `remainingTime` in the currentTableState, generating a new state for the tail call).

My **question** is: How do I retrieve the elapsed time since `receive`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

1. Add a second argument to the function with a default value of 15000, which is the total timeout.
2. When the function starts, store the current time.
3. When it enters the `any_junk` branch, subtract the time elapsed from remaining and then make the recursive call.

```
defp ask_option_on_no_bet(currentTableState, remaining \\ 15000) do
  start = now()
  user = currentTableState.currentUser
  newTableState = receive do
    { ^user, :bet, amount } -> ...
    { ^user, :check } -> ...
    { ^user, :fold } -> ...
    any_junk ->
      elapsed = now() - start
      ask_option_on_no_bet(currentTableState, remaining - elapsed)
    after remaining ->
      process_check(currentTableState)
  end
end
```

`now()` is just a simple function that returns the current monotonic time in milliseconds:

```
defp now, do: System.monotonic_time(:millisecond)
```

Comment: I'm taking this one!